When attempting to retrieve another member's profile details via the LinkedIn People API, a "Invalid Member ID" error is encountered
As part of our ongoing efforts to leverage LinkedIn's APIs, we have successfully created an application on the LinkedIn Developer page and obtained access to the Advertising API product. This has enabled us to configure OAuth 2.0 scopes in the Auth Tab, as specified by the LinkedIn team.
The following permissions have been granted under my OAuth 2.0 scopes section:

r_ads_reporting: Retrieve reporting for advertising accounts

Retrieve organization social data: Retrieve organization posts, comments, reactions, and engagement data

rw_organization_admin: Manage organization pages and retrieve reporting data

w_member_social: Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on behalf of the member

r_ads: Retrieve advertising accounts

w_organization_social: Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on behalf of the organization

rw_ads: Manage advertising accounts

r_basicprofile: Use basic profile information (name, photo, headline, public profile URL)

r_organization_admin: Retrieve organization pages and reporting data (including follower, visitor, and content analytics)

r_1st_connections_size: Retrieve the number of 1st-degree connections within the network


Following the instructions provided in the email from the LinkedIn team, we utilized the documentation to fork the Campaign Management API's and environments, as well as obtain an access token.
However, upon reviewing the available campaign management APIs, we noted that the /people endpoint was not included. To address this, we created a new GET request with the base URL set to https://api.linkedin.com/rest. We also added the necessary header for the /people endpoint:

X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0


When attempting to retrieve a person's profile information using the following API call:
GET --> {{baseUrl}}/people/(id:vijay-s-xxxx)
We encountered an error with the following response:

{

"message": "Invalid Member Id",

"status": 403

}

We have successfully utilized the GET {{baseUrl}}/me API endpoint to retrieve our own profile information, and are receiving the expected response.
However, when attempting to access another user's profile data using the GET {{baseUrl}}/people/{id} endpoint, we are encountering difficulties. Specifically, we are passing in the ID value extracted from the LinkedIn profile URL structure https://www.linkedin.com/in/(id: {personId})/, which we assume represents a unique identifier for the user.
Despite following the API documentation and guidelines, we are not receiving the desired response. Instead, an error with a status code of 403 (Forbidden) is being returned. We would appreciate any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it in order to successfully retrieve profile information for another user using the LinkedIn API.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Hi @DarkBee, I appreciate your suggestion to provide a minimal reproducible example, but unfortunately, this question isn't related to coding. It's actually about working with LinkedIn APIs. Would you be able to help me with that?

If your question is not about programming, then why did you post it on StackOverflow? Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]
